# IN VS2015 Existing Angular 2 Application Type Script Intellisence is not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

IN VS2015 Existing Angular 2 Application Type Script Intellisence is not Working,For new Application it is working fine can anyone help me on this issue.

Comment: Restart the visual studio it will work for you. if not work than you have to convert that project into typescript as vs2015 gives popup while opening the typescript project.

Comment: Hi Muralikrishna, all existing Angular 2 Application Type Script projects have this issue or just the specific one? If it is only happening to the specific one, please try to remove the .vs folder under the solution store folder. If not, please have a try with: clean up the VS 2015 cache folder: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and check it, or go to Start-Visual Studio 2015 folder and run the ‘Developer Command Prompt for VS 2015’ as administrator, then run the command: devenv /resetuserdata to test it, restart the VS 2015 and reopen the solution to check it again.